# override len function for derived class of set

Tags: python

I am trying to write a class that behaves like a set with every possible object imaginable in it. This will allow me to neatly refine sets by successive intersections. E.g. if I have some constructor for this object, let us call it UniversalSet(), then I want to do something like the following:

```
myset = UniversalSet()
for subset in subsets:
    myset = myset & subset
```

The final `myset` object will be an intersection of all `set` objects in `subset`.

Now I know there are other ways to achieve the above, but partly as an intellectual exercise, and partly because I see this as having potential reuse, I have implemented the following:

```
class UniversalSet(set):
    """
    A set that contains every object.
    As we don't know what every object consists of, we just assume that
    adding anything doesn't change it, and testing for anything in that
    set returns true.    

    Use case is for continual refinement, e.g.:
    myset = UniversalSet()
    for subset in subsets:
        myset = myset & subset

    """
    def __and__(self,other):
        if type(other) is UniversalSet:
            return self
        elif type(other) is set:
            return other
        raise TypeError('Cannot "and" UniversalSet with non-set')

    def __contains__(self,elem):
        return True

    def __eq__(self,other):
        if type(other) is UniversalSet:
            return True
        elif type(other) is set:
            return False
        raise TypeError(
            'Cannot compare UniversalSet with non-set')

    def __ge__(self,other):
        if type(other) is UniversalSet:
            return True
        elif type(other) is set:
            return True
        raise TypeError(
            'Cannot compare UniversalSet with non-set')

    def __gt__(self,other):
        if type(other) is UniversalSet:
            return False
        elif type(other) is set:
            return True
        raise TypeError(
            'Cannot compare UniversalSet with non-set')

    def __iand__(self,other):
        self = self.__and__(other)
        return self

    def __init__(self):
        super(UniversalSet,self).__init__([])

    def __ior__(self,other):
        if type(other) is UniversalSet:
            return self
        elif type(other) is set:
            return self
        raise TypeError('Cannot "or" UniversalSet with non-set')

    def __isub__(self,other):
        raise TypeError('Cannot subtract from universal set')

    def __iter__(self):
        raise TypeError('Cannot iterate through universal set')

    def __ixor__(self,other):
        raise TypeError('Cannot ixor universal set')

    def __le__(self):
        if type(other) is UniversalSet:
            return True
        elif type(other) is set:
            return False
        raise TypeError(
            'Cannot compare UniversalSet with non-set')        

    def __len__(self):
        return self.len()

    def len(self):
        return int_inf.IntegerInfinity()

    def __lt__(self,other):
        if type(other) is UniversalSet:
            return False
        elif type(other) is set:
            return False
        raise TypeError(
            'Cannot compare UniversalSet with non-set')        

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'UniversalSet()'

    def __str__(self):
        return 'UniversalSet()'

    def __sub__(self,other):
        raise TypeError('Cannot subtract from universal set')

    def __or__(self,other):
        if type(other) is UniversalSet:
            return self
        elif type(other) is set:
            return self
        raise TypeError('Cannot or UniversalSet with non-set')
```

You will notice that the `len` function uses a special object, because a normal infinity object is not of the required type of `int`. So I implement the additional `IntegerInfinity` object. Here it is:

```
import numpy as np

class IntegerInfinity(int):
    def __eq__(self,other):
        if type(other) is IntegerInfinity:
            return True
        return False

    def __ge__(self,other):
        if type(other) is IntegerInfinity:
            return True
        if other == np.inf:
            return False
        elif type(other) is float or type(other) is int:
            return True
        raise TypeError(
            'Cannot compare type %r with IntegerInfinity' % type(other))

    def __gt__(self,other):
        if type(other) is IntegerInfinity:
            return False
        elif other == np.inf:
            return False
        elif type(other) is float or type(other) is int:
            return True
        raise TypeError(
            'Cannot compare type %r with IntegerInfinity' % type(other))

    def __le__(self,other):
        if type(other) is IntegerInfinity:
            return True
        if other == np.inf:
            return True
        elif type(other) is float or type(other) is int:
            return False
        raise TypeError(
            'Cannot compare type %r with IntegerInfinity' % type(other))

    def __lt__(self,other):
        if type(other) is IntegerInfinity:
            return False
        elif other == np.inf:
            return True
        elif type(other) is float or type(other) is int:
            return False
        raise TypeError(
            'Cannot compare type %r with IntegerInfinity' % type(other))

    def __init__(self):
        super(int,self).__init__(0)

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'int_inf'

    def __str__(self):
        return 'int_inf'
```

The rest of `UniversalSet` all seems to work quite nicely for me except that when I call `len` on my object, it doesn't give my nice `IntegerInfinity` object. Instead it gives `0`, i.e.

```
>>> uniset  = UniversalSet()
>>> # desired result
... IntegerInfinity()
int_inf
>>> # actual result
... len(uniset)
0
```

Moreover, this zero seems to be coming from nowhere. I have tried a different dummy set in the `__init__` function of `UniversalSet`, and I have tried a different dummy integer value in the `__init__` function of `IntegerInfinity`, but neither change the above output.

Can anyone explain why this is happening? And/or suggest a workaround that gives me my `UniversalSet`?

Martijn's answer below covers things I think. The answer is not to implement a `len` or `__len__` function, and drop the `IntegerInfinity` object. Even better, I will raise an error if `len` is called.

Comment: I would think that since `int` is an immutable type, you'd need to do some initialization in `__new__`.  As it is, `IntegerInfinity` has an integral *value* of 0 ...

Comment: I will investigate the `__new__` function as you suggest, but changing the `__init__` function of `IntegerInfinity` to e.g. `super(int,self).__init__(3)`, does not affect the output of `len(uniset)`.

Comment: @pandamonium: integers are immutable, so you cannot set the value in `__init__` (the object is already created by that time). You'd have to do that in `__new__`. However, you'd have to set it to an integer value in the range `0` through to `sys.maxsize`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `len()` function will cast anything the `__len__` method returns to `int`, using the [`PyInt_AsSsize_t()` API function](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/int.html?highlight=pyint_asssize_t#PyInt_AsSsize_t):

> Will first attempt to cast the object to a `PyIntObject` or `PyLongObject`, if it is not already one, and then return its value as `Py_ssize_t`.

where `Py_ssize_t` is your architecture pointer size (64 or 32 bit usually). See the [source for the `type.slot_sq_length` slot](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/5609135c6e86/Objects/typeobject.c#l4940).

Because you subclassed `int` but did not provide a `__new__` method, it has the the default value `0` when cast back to `int()`.

You cannot hope to get your custom type through the `len()` function as a return value; `len()` always returns an `int()`; the best you can hope to achieve is to return `sys.maxsize`.

If your object is meant to be unsized, you probably should not implement a `__len__` *at all*. Make your object an iterator instead.

Comment: Thank you Martijn, this is helpful. What I wanted was for the output of len to be greater than (not equal to) any length of a normal set. However, this was purely for completeness, I don't have a use case. I will take your final advice and not implement a len function. Finally, I can't implement an iterator, but I don't want to.